# What happens if one OpenMP thread crashes?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Consider the following case of a parallel `for`/`do`-loop:

```
     PARALLEL DO 
   thread 1                      thread 2
   line 1                        line 1

   line k                    ->  line k

-> line l                        line l

   line n                        line n
```

Now, thread 1 encounters an exception or an error (segmentation fault) on line `l` and terminates. What will happen to thread 2? Will it immediately stop? Will it continue to line `l` as well (whether or not it encouters the same error there)? Will it continue to the next synchronization step? Or to the next step where it accesses shared memory of both threads (in particular output devices like standard error)?

I didn't find a hint in the OpenMP 4.0 specifications.

Comment: It's probably better to post this to the OpenMP forum where the experts will see it. In any case, are you trapping the segfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMP is not fault-tolerant. The standard's silence on the topic indicates that anything could happen -- a program enters the realm of undefined behaviour.

That aside, a segfault is (usually) a process problem, not a thread problem.  After all, all OpenMP threads share the same memory and the same address space.  Your phrase *where it accesses shared memory of both threads* hints that you may think that threads have private memory at some points during the computation.  Well, only in a way -- threads have private variables. That just means the compiler creates copies of them for thread-specific use.  They're all in the same process address space. If you wrote a clever code (perhaps using pointers) which enabled one thread to access another thread's private variables you would not cause the o/s to raise a segmentation fault.

I don't believe I've ever encountered an OpenMP program in which a single thread failed.  Is your question of more than theoretical interest ?  Have you experienced such a problem ?

Comment: My code hits a floating point exception if it runs with multiple threads. That triggered my general interest, what other threads do if one of them fails.

Comment: I see. So, like all well-disciplined code (ha ha) you'd catch the exception, in the thread that triggered it, and deal with it.  Notwithstanding, OpenMP is going to fail very quickly after the unhandled exception brings a thread to its knees.